# [MongoDB Ops Manager]mongo.mongoUri ops manager db hosts connection not working

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services

I have installed MongoDB Ops Manager Database [3 instances]
/etc/mongod.conf -> bindIp: 0.0.0.0
And I have Installed Ops Manager Application
In /conf/conf-mms.properties my config for mongo.mongoUri is below

```
mongo.mongoUri=mongodb://1.2.3.4:27017,5.6.7.8:27017,9.10.11.12:27017
```

**Error:**

> Failure to connect to configured mongo instance: Config{loadBalance=false.....
> pre-flight is getting failed

**Notes:**

1. mongod is running in all db servers
2. If single db is mentioned in mongo.mongoUri then application can connect to that database like `mongo.mongoUri=mongodb://1.2.3.4:27017`
3. I guess I need to create as replica set as per doc so i tried below command in main database server

   ```
    mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /home/ubuntu/data/appdb --replSet rs0 --bind_ip localhost,5.6.7.8,9.10.11.12
   ```

   > {"t":{"$date":"2021-01-06T17:36:07.509+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20568,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Error setting up listener","attr":{"error":{"code":9001,"codeName":"SocketException","errmsg":"Cannot assign requested address"}}}

Comment: check  those IP addresses , are they from same server , how they resolve via  ping or nslookup ...

Comment: They are private ips of different instances,I am getting the dnsname when nslookup is given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is fixed. Single(standalone) database host was able to connect. But for multiple databases to connect we need to implement replica set first for the mongodb databases.